# Django function to return the result of MongoDB aggregate pipeline

Tags: python-3.x, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregate-functions, pymongo-3.x

I would really appreciate if someone can help me with this. I need Django (Python) function to inject some parameters into a pipeline script, pass it to MongoDB Atlas and receive the result in a cursor.

```
from bson import ObjectId
import pymongo

conn = "connection string"
client = pymongo.MongoClient(conn) 

pipeline = [
    <<pipeline script>>
    ]

out = client.db.mycollection.aggregate(pipeline)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using Djongo to connect the Django ORM to MongoDB, you could use the provided [DjongoManager](https://nesdis.github.io/djongo/get-started/#djongo-manager) as the manager for your Model, and use PyMongo functions using the `mongo_` prefix. Here's a quick example:

models.py

```
from djongo import models

class Message(models.Model):
    text = models.CharField(max_length=150)

    objects = models.DjongoManager()
```

Then in the shell you could do something like:

```
>>> from core.models import *

>>> cursor = Message.objects.mongo_aggregate('pipeline')
```